# Cancel ajax request from chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to cancel the ajax request from `chrome developer tools` after it has initiated. For example I want to test my fallback message is showing correctly. I can set `No throttling` to `Offline` so that all calls will fail, but I just want to test one `API` to fail, for debugging purposes.

[image: Developer tools]

I know I can use `abort()` methods, (ie I can do it through JavaScript). I dont want to touch the code for just this need.

There's a `replay XHR` option in right click of the API, It'll be great there is something like `abort XHR` in same way. But there isn't.

Comment: You can using any Ad Blocker extension (like [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm)), add a rule to block any URL you want for debug (although its main function is to block ads :D).

Comment: That's a nice hack. Thanks

Comment: You can turn off wifi or unplug cable after triggering the call!

Comment: I think this is a valid request and the workarounds offered so far do not solve the problem. I would be happy to read better ones. Any other ideas?

Comment: *I know I can use `abort()` methods ...* Anyway, abort won't do what you want : it doesn't fire an error event, and you won't be able to test your fallback message.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple trick I use. Pressing **F5** while in the tab immediately followed by **ESC**.

XHR requests still active by chrome are canceled before the new answer is loaded.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only way that cancels running requests.

Comment: Pressing F5 reloads the page, no matter how fast I click at escape.

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems I have to hit the ESC key twice: F5 > ESC > ESC.

Answer (score 5):

From Chrome 59 you can block specific requests from Network tab of developer tools itself.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#block-requests

Right-click on the request in the Network panel and select Block Request URL. A new Request blocking tab pops up in the Drawer, which lets you manage blocked requests.

So, In my case, I will run the code block that specific API and then re-run. :)

As per the comment, this is not exactly canceling the already started request, but checking how the app behaves if only one request is failed by blocking only one request. Thanks @Ross Ivantsiv for this.

[image: screenshot for blocking request]

Comment: Blocking requests has nothing to do with canceling pending requests.

Comment: Oh. Updated the answer. But for the requirement of how the app will work, if one API is failed, we can block the request.

Comment: I think the question is how to cancel the AJAX request!

Comment: This was such a waste of time, how did this answer even get any upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't know the exact URL, You can debug all XHR by adding an XHR breakpoint within the **Sources** tab

[image]

[image]

2. Or **if you know the name or part of XHR** URL which you need to debug you can add it XHR by clicking the ( + ) icon.

[image]